What structures can follow "hence"? Noun => Yes, but what about Adverbs, Clauses?
I mostly see nouns or noun phrases following hence. What about other grammatical components? Are the following sentences correct?

Flashing lights and camera lenses may put the judge, who must always be of sound mind, off his stride and hence affect his judgments.
She put her make-up on and hence beautiful at the prom.
The company lost a great deal of money. Hence, the CEO was asked to resign.


Are you comfortable with the rules governing "therefore"? They're the same rules.

Are they? I've never seen "therefore" preceding noun phrases before. To my knowledge, therefore + Verbs/Clauses and hence + nouns/noun phrases. But then, I saw the third example in M-W and the first example elsewhere, so my belief system kinda fell apart at that point, hence the question.

Good point, that's sort of the prime use case for "hence". I weaken my claim, but they're interchangeable in most cases including these.

I would use thus in the first two, but (2) is ungrammatical - and thus [she] looked beautiful at the prom.

@KateBunting Do you mean you would use thus in the first and the third one? I'm a bit confused.

As I said, I would use thus in (1) and (2) (with the amendment I suggested). I would probably use therefore in (3).

I find #2 ungrammatical.
